Finding the best way for combining features non-linearly within a linear regression
Problem Statement
I have a set of two features, $X_1$ and $X_2$ that I combine to try and predict a target variable in a regression of the form: $ Y_0 = \frac{X_1 - X_2}{X_1 + X_2} $. You can think of this as an interpolation between the two, normalizing the difference to be between $[-1, 1]$ for all data points.
$X_1, X_2$ are non-linearly affected by some other features: $Z_1, Z_2$.
I'm trying to find a way to improve the original regression, $Y_0$, with some function $f$ so that $Y_1 = \frac{f(X_1, Z_1) - f(X_2, Z_2)}{f(X_1, Z_1) + f(X_2, Z_2)} $ improves upon $Y_0$.
I have a good idea of what class of function to start with. But I'm realizing ideally I'd want to tune whichever function I use to my specific problem. So if I'm using an exponential function: $f(X_i, Z_i) = X_i * e^{Z_i} $, I want to find the optimal parameter lambda where $f(X_i, Z_i, \lambda) = X_i * e^{\lambda * Z_i} $ provides the best possible fit. ($\lambda$ is a fixed value for all data points)

Concrete Example
I think it would be easier to put things into an example. Let's imagine that we are trying to predict the angle a see-saw will tilt by conducting many balancing experiments. $Y=1$ means $X_1$ is (infinitely) heavier, and the seesaw is touching the floor on that side. Similarly, $Y=-1$ means $X_2$ is infinitely heavier, see-saw is touching the floor on the respective side. In a perfect world, this target variable is exactly determined by the relative masses of the two. This is the initial simple regression from earlier, $Y_0$.
But now we have an unknown force acting on each object: $Z_1$ and $Z_2$. We have a value for the force on each side, but we don't know how it affects the imbalance exactly. Think of it as Alien Gravity. Below is a crude diagram of what I mean by all of this, hope it helps. 
But now we have this weird force that we want to find a perfect way to model.
The real data is different, so please allow some creative imagination in this example :)

My Progress:
I tried to regress $Y = \beta_1 X_1 + \beta_2 X_2 + \alpha$, broken down by for each decile of $Z_1$ and $Z_2$, and then plotting the coefficients vs. decile. I found that as $Z_1$ increases, the coefficient of $X_1$ increases in an exponential manner, and the same (but negative) for $X_2$ and $Z_2$. So this indicates my hypothesis of there being an exponential relationship is likely correct.

My Questions:
"In an exponential manner" is very hand-wavy. I'd like to have a sound approach to this modeling process. I need to find the optimal lambda, and also confirm that exponential fit is even the best option. Not entirely sure how to go about that.

What I've Tried
I tried fitting an exponential curve to the coefficients vs. decile plot, and that gave some value for lambda. But the problem is that doesn't work when I do the full regression? Just trying a bunch of values for lambda doesn't sound right either, and feels like over-fitting. I did it, and the optimal lambda was completely different than the one I got from the other method. So I'm completely lost now.

Any guidance on how to even start approaching or looking up this problem would be greatly appreciated!
